# Stacksmashing without even accessing any data

Tags: c, local-variables, stack-smash

On my machine, the following code apparently produces stacksmashing:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void function2(int* data);
void function1();

void function2(int* data)
{
    printf("grps ");
    printf(" ");
    printf(" one more line\n");
}

void function1()
{
    printf("function1_checkpoint1\n");
    int *tempData[520721];
    function2(tempData);
}

int main()
{
    printf("main_checkpoint1\n");
    function1();
    printf("main_checkpoint2\n");
    return 0;
}
```

If it does not crash on your machine, try replacing `520721` by some more crazy number like 10 million. The output I have is:

```
main_checkpoint1
```

And then crash. If I replace `520721` by `520720` I get:

```
main_checkpoint1
function1_checkpoint1
```

And then also crash. If instead I replace `printf(" ")` by `printf("")` (suppress the space, printing an empty string), the program is running normally and I get

```
main_checkpoint1
function1_checkpoint1
grps  one more line
main_checkpoint2
```

Finally, replacing `int *tempData[520721];` by `int *tempData=malloc(520721*sizeof(int));` with subsequent testing of the success of `malloc()` and usage of `free(tempData);` have always worked in all the cases I tested.

As you can see, all I am doing is calling a first function in `main`, which creates a very big local `int` table, and then passing the pointer to this `int` table, to a second function. And the second function does nothing except `printf`s and doesn't even touch to the pointer or the data it points to.

I was just wondering what on earth was going on in my machine...why is this code producing a crash?

Thanks very much for your insight!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's crashing because you're causing a stack overflow. That huge array is allocated on the stack, and the stack isn't *that* big.

Simply *allocating* a variable is enough to make it move the stack pointer. You don't write to it, but when you then call your other function, your program tries to write to the stack, *past* the huge array, to allocate the next stack frame. This is when it crashes.

You've already got the solution: use a dynamic allocation instead.

Comment: Yes but why...I am not writing anything to the int table!

Comment: The simple fact that it exists still moves the stack pointer.

Comment: this means that even when the size of the array is known in advance and fixed, you still have limitations to respect?

Comment: Yes. You still have a stack size to respect. On Windows the default stack size is 1MB. Stack overflowing is the result of smashing that limit, because you're nesting too many calls, or because you're trying to use too much stack space, or a combination of both. For sizeable allocations, you need to use dynamic allocations.

Comment: I did not know that. I thought that upon compilation of a static executable, the size needed in memory would be signaled to the OS somehow..I did not know this 1MB limit on Windows, I thought stack smashing only occurred when one function was writing outside of some array on purpose. You taught me something! Thanks!